# Spark 2.4 Unable to Insert Record using variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to insert record into a table using a variable but it is failing.

command:

```
val query = "INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('LOGS','RUN_DATE',{} )".format(s"$RUN_DATE")
spark.sql(s"query")
spark.sql("INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('LOGS','ExtractStartTimestamp',$ExtractStartTimestamp)")
```

error:

```
INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('SDEDLOGS','ExtractStartTimestamp',$ExtractStartTimestamp)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're confused with string interpolation... you need to put `s` before the last query so that the variable is substituted into the string. Also the first two lines can be simplified:

```
val query = s"INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('LOGS','RUN_DATE',$RUN_DATE)"
spark.sql(query)
spark.sql(s"INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('LOGS','ExtractStartTimestamp',$ExtractStartTimestamp)")
```

Comment: Hi MCK, thanks for your suggestion, it is working as expected :) But now I am having another problem. Everytime this runs, only few records get inserted into the table and a new parquet file is created. That means if I run this everyday, one new small file will be created. I need to avoid it. I am thinking of using insert overwrite at the end with some merge set commands but spark is not allowing insert overwrite. Any idea how it can be handled.?

Comment: If you have a new question, please click the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question. There is not enough space in the comments section to answer your question. Thanks! @Ratan